# Dynamically register BroadcastReceiver with IntentFilter and let AlarmManager handle PendingIntent

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, intentfilter

Using a virtual Pixel 5 (API 28 Android 9.0), I would like to pass the instance of my class `MainActivity` to the inner class `MyAlarm`, but since statically declaring the receiver in the manifest would result in an instantiation error, I decided to create it dynamically. I don't know what the argument `action` of `IntentFilter` is supposed to be in my case. I tried several things, but it is hard to troubleshoot without an error. `onReceive()` just doesn't get executed. Also, is `IntentFilter` even usable, because I want to set an exact alarm using `AlarmManager`? Here is a shorter version of my code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object {
        const val REQUEST_ID = 843
        const val NOTIFICATION_ID = 349
        const val NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "9552"
    }
    lateinit var myAlarm : MyAlarm

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        myAlarm = MyAlarm(this)
        val intentFilter = IntentFilter("")
        registerReceiver(myAlarm, intentFilter)
        setAlarm(System.currentTimeMillis() + 4000)

    private fun setAlarm(timeInMillis: Long) {
        val intent = Intent(this, myAlarm::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, REQUEST_ID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        val alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, timeInMillis, pendingIntent)

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        unregisterReceiver(myAlarm)
    }


    class MyAlarm(var mainActivityInstance: MainActivity) : BroadcastReceiver() {
        lateinit var mediaPlayer : MediaPlayer

        override fun onReceive(
            context: Context,
            intent: Intent
        ) {
            if (!this::mediaPlayer.isInitialized) {
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sea_waves)
                mediaPlayer.isLooping = true
            }
            createNotificationChannel(context)
            sendNotification(context, "ALARM", "Wake up", "")
            mediaPlayer.start()
            // Calling method of mainActivityInstance here

        private fun createNotificationChannel(context: Context) {
            val name = "Alarm Clock Light Channel"
            val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            val channel = NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, name, importance)
            NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }

        private fun sendNotification(context: Context, title: String, text: String, detail_text: String) {
            val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(androidx.core.R.drawable.notification_icon_background)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(text)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(detail_text))
            NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build())
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want to do. Set an alarm and when it goes off open your media player activity to play a song or something?

Don't pass activity instances to broadcast receivers. They have very different lifecycle. Secondly dynamic broadcast receivers only exist while your process is alive. Use a fullscreen intent in your notification to let NotificationManager launch your activity.

See here: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/time-sensitive

Create a static receiver that reacts to your alarm. There post your notification with the fullscreen intent.